# Can't find packages: eid-mw eid-viewer in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, smartcard

My smart card reader was working in Ubuntu 16.04, but I can't find beidgui, libacr38u, libacr38ucontrol0 and libacr38ucontrol-dev packages that are required for installing the same PC/SC smart card reader drivers
in Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the 16.04 smart card reader .deb files from Ubuntu 16.04 and double-click each .deb file to install it manually in Ubuntu 18.04.

Run the following commands in Ubuntu 18.04 to install dependency packages:

```
sudo apt update    
sudo apt install pcscd libpcsclite1 libpcsclite-dev libusb-0.1-4
```

Manually download these three .deb files from the official Ubuntu website.

- [libacr38](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libacr38u/download)
- [libacr38ucontrol0](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libacr38ucontrol0/download)
- [libacr38ucontrol-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libacr38ucontrol-dev/download)

The software for reading the Belgian electronic identity card (*beidgui*) has been discontinued in Ubuntu since later releases than Ubuntu 12.04, but the source code for beidgui is still available from its [GitHub](https://github.com/fedict/eid-mw) webpage which also has instructions for installing it.

This repository contains the software and viewer for the Belgian electronic identity card. With this, you can:

- Communicate with secure websites that require eID authentication
- Sign documents and emails using your eID
- Using the viewer, read the identity data on eID cards, verify their validity, and store them for future usage
- Using the provided API, do all of the above in custom applications of your own.

Comment: followd your recommendations , but can't even open the EID card raeder

Comment: Failed to add module "Belgium eID". Probable cause : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbeidpkcs11.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory".
  Can this help  ?

Comment: can't find pakket eid-viewer ,neither eid-mw